# How can I use XHTML codepieces in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports, xhtml

I am trying to automate the creation of a report for our software and the datebase has String formatted XHTML code as entries. Those entries should be convertet into design for the finished report. they also contain images that have to be carried over as well. I can't find anything about this anywhere, so I want to ask if it is even possible to do that and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience with JasperReports, I literally never heard of any possibility of using XHTML in a report. You know, JasperReports is a tool that let's you create a template for your reports with the possibility of importing data from different data source (JSON, MySQL, Oracle, XLS and XLSX files ...) and since it's XML based, it gives you a very structured report and data for later usage, you can manipulate those data howerver you wanted : Create dashboards, tables, billing, using subreports in reports and lots of other tools that makes creating long and complicated reports easy. JasperReports is not a navigator, the only way I know of to print `HTML` contents in a report is by using the `HTML component` in `Report Elements`
I've never tried this before so I don't know if JasperReports supports `.xhtml` format or it's working only with `.html`, since the syntax is not much different, it's just a lot more structed, then you can simply change your code to `.html` and case it doesn't work with xhtml
Good luck

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have a `HTML component` in the basic elements of my palette. I am using the eclipse plugin btw.

Comment: The `HTML Component` is not supported in the eclipse plugin version, it's kinda old version if you think about it this way. The plugin you are using is very limited, it would be for the best if you create your reports using iReport Designer or the JasperReports software since it has a lot more options and also you can manipulate your report more easily. Then you can use the `.jasper` file in your java code without any problems. This is what I'm doing btw, generate my `.jasper` report file with iReport Designer 5.6.0 and then use that file in my code, you'll only need the necessary libraries